# GCM Demo Application's failure to register to tomcat server

Tags: android, tomcat

i have tried and finished 90% of GCM Demo application for android from the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html So i would like to ask your favour for the following error. I googled and referred many websites and forums for the solution. But i could not figure it out. So please help me. Thank you.[image]

Comment: You should post more information with your question so that to help people to help you. Post server logs, logcat logs and information regarding what your setup is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the helper libraries and make required changes to the emulator.

1. Goto your android SDK folder and open SDK Manager and install Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library under Extras section. (If you don’t see Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library update your SDK manager to latest version)
2. After installing the library it will create gcm.jar file in your Andoird_SDK_Folder\extras\google\gcm\gcm-client\dist. Later you need to add this .jar file to your android project.
3. Now open your AVD Manager and create a new Google API emulator and start the emulator. (Note: To test gcm application in emulator you need to test it on Google API device only)
4. After launching emulator press Menu button goto Settings. Select Accounts & Sync. And then press Add Account button and add a Google account.

Finally Test your Application on Simulator.